# Junit and Mockito for ATG

Tags: java, atg

I have created a class, which extended CommerceItemManager and overrided createCommerceItem method. And now i want to write a junit and Mockito test for this class.
Here is a basic logic for test class:

```
public class CustomizeCommerceItemManagerTest {

    @Spy @InjectMocks CustomizeCommerceItemManager commerceItemManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething(){
    }
}
```

But when ever i run this class, it throws an exception:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   atg.nucleus.logging.ClassLoggingFactory.getFactory(ClassLoggingFactory.java:106)
>     at
>   atg.core.i18n.LayeredResourceBundle.(LayeredResourceBundle.java:153)
>     at
>   atg.commerce.order.CommerceItemManager.(CommerceItemManager.java:93)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for
>   base name atg.nucleus.NucleusResources, locale en_US  at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)  at
>   atg.nucleus.GenericContext.(GenericContext.java:113)  ... 46
>   more

I found out that inside CommerceItemManager have a parameter:

```
protected static ResourceBundle sResourceBundle = LayeredResourceBundle.getBundle("atg.commerce.order.OrderResources", LangLicense.getLicensedDefault());
```

and i have tried using PorwerMock to mock this parameter but it doesnt help.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LayeredResourceBundle.class})
public class CustomizeCommerceItemManagerTest {

    private CustomizeCommerceItemManager commerceItemManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockStatic(LayeredResourceBundle.class);
        when(LayeredResourceBundle.getBundle("atg.commerce.order.OrderResources", LangLicense.getLicensedDefault())).thenReturn(null);
        commerceItemManager = PowerMockito.spy(new CustomizeCommerceItemManager());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: It appears to be complaining that the en_US resource bundle is missing. Can you confirm that this is the bundle your code is returning?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved it by using Powermock like you did and creating a fake ResourceBundle.

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

     ResourceBundle resourceBundle = new ResourceBundle() {
        @Override
        protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
            return "fake_translated_value";
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
            return Collections.emptyEnumeration();
        }
    };

    mockStatic(LayeredResourceBundle.class);
    when(LayeredResourceBundle.getBundle(anyString(), any(java.util.Locale.class))).thenReturn(resourceBundle);
}
```

Hope this can help.